# bash command inside a function to delete all files except the recent 5

Tags: bash

I have a delete backup files function which takes in the arguments as a directory name and to backup the files of a specific directory and specific type of file like this **delete_old_backup_files $(dirname $$abc) "$abc.*"**

The function body is:

```
local fpath=$1
local fexpr=$2

   # delete backup files older than a day
   find $fpath -name "${fexpr##*/}" -mmin +1 -type f | xargs rm -f
```

Currently deleting files that are older than a day. Now I want to modify the function such that this function should delete all backup files of type $abc.*,  except the last 5 backup files created. Tried various commands using stat or -printf but couldn't succeed.

What is the correct way of completing this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the filenames do not contain newline characters, would you please
try:

```
delete_old_backup_files() {
    local fpath=$1
    local fexpr=$2

    find "$fpath" -type f -name "${fexpr##*/}" -printf "%T@\t%p\n" | sort -nr | tail -n +6 | cut -f2- | xargs rm -f --
}
```

- `-printf "%T@\t%p\n"` prints the seconds since epoch (`%T@`) followed
  by a tab character (`\t`) then the filename (`%p`) and a newline (`\n`).
- `sort -nr` numerically sorts the lines in descending order (newer first,
  older last).
- `tail -n +6` prints the 6th and following lines.
- `cut -f2-` removes the prepended timestamp leaving the filename only.

**[Edit]**
In case of `MacOS`, please try instead (not tested):

```
find "$fpath" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m%t%N" | sort -nr | tail -n +6 | cut -f2- | xargs rm --
```

In the `stat` command, `%m` is expanded to the modification time (seconds since epoch), `%t` is replaced with a tab, and `%N` to be a filename.

Comment: find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

I don't know why but when I use print f and stat I get the above error.

Comment: Are you using MacOS?

Comment: yes I'm using MacOS

Comment: My apology. The `find` command in MacOS does not support `-printf` option. I'll try to find an alternative. BR.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a MacOS alternative. The script is not tested as I do not have the MacOS working environment. If it still does not work, any kind of feedback is welcome. BR.

Comment: I've tested the command and it worked well, just an update on this. So in my scenario I need to find a specific file in a specific directory. So I updated the command to be `    find "$fpath" -name "${fexpr##*/}" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m%t%N" | sort -nr | tail -n +6 | cut -f2- | xargs rm --` 

Thank you so much @tshiono for your support.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. If you feel my answer
solves well your problem, I'd appreciate if you can accept my answer by
clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.

Answer (score 0):

I would use sorting instead of find. You can use `ls -t`

```bash
$ touch a b c
$ sleep 3
$ touch d e f
ls -t | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -n +4
a
b
c
$ ls -t | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -n +4 | xargs rm
$ ls
d  e  f
```

From `man ls`:

```
-t     sort by modification time, newest first
```

Make sure you create backups before you delete stuff :-)

Comment: Note: You have to do something with filenames with spaces. I'd suggest circumvent them in the first place.

Comment: yes but ls -t lists all the recent files. I need only the files of specific extension as mentioned in the function. 

delete_old_backup_files $(dirname $$abc) "$abc.*"
local fpath=$1
local fexpr=$2

   # delete backup files older than a day
   find $fpath -name "${fexpr##*/}" -mmin +1 -type f | xargs rm -f